# Detect when users take screenshots of my program

Tags: windows, security, screenshot

I'm writing a Windows application. How can I tell when a screenshot is being taken of it? I read about how to detect the hotkey being pressed, but I'm more worried about the case where every 100 ms or so another program is taking screenshots of it. Namely, I'm trying to notice when someone creates another program (say a python one using ImageGrab, as mentioned in another post) which constantly takes screenshots of my app and uses them to read info off of it.

I don't care much about preventing the screenshots from being taken - I can just ban the user once this behavior is noticed.

Is this possible? Is there a windows message sent when any app takes a screenshot, like with WM_HOTKEY? Or does windows just use the latest info from the latest paint events, and return that to the other program directly, without my app being able to notice at all?

Comment: You want to ban people who take screenshots of your app?

Comment: Very closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767212/programattically-taking-screenshots-in-windows-without-the-application-noticing

Comment: @jinguy: this would be a very useful thing to do for an application that displays sensitive data...

Comment: I am very, very curious why you would like to detect screenshots (and take such aggressive actions). I can already tell you that detecting the key is possible, but the action itself is not.. There are a lot of programs out there who take screenshots in many different ways. How about screen capturing (on video..) are you blocking that too?

Comment: I suppose sensitive data could pose problems if it got out.

Comment: @David: And posted by the same person.

Comment: @Adam: interesting, I didn't notice

Comment: Can you tell us why you need to do this? and maybe a bit about the environment where this "shy" application is used?.. We might come up with some other solution to your problem...

Comment: @all: Yes, this is really the same question, but I re-worded it this way to get more interesting answers =). Feel free to close the other one.

Comment: Can you not ban the user when they use the screenshot-derived information? Preventing or detecting the user screenshot'ing your application seems like the wrong way to go about this (mostly because it is "impossible")

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790190/is-it-possible-to-protect-from-downloading-a-video-from-a-site/ (the question is about video, but the issue is the same for pictures)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Whatever you do, people will find a way around it. Suppose such a method existed, where you could reliably detect another program taking a screenshot of your application. To get around that, I could install VirtualBox, run your application inside the VM, and then have a program take screenshots of VirtualBox (which then contains your application). Your application would have absolutely no way to know it was having its picture taken.

Comment: Unless VirtualBox simulates taking screenshots the same way windows does. From your answer, you're saying that it doesn't?

Comment: I'm not talking about VirtualBox taking the screenshot; I'm talking about another program taking a screenshot *of* VirtualBox. After all, VirtualBox is basically just a window with some pixels in it.

Comment: Here's what I meant. In my head, a certain function gets called when "takeScreenshot()" is called. This function would recursively call the "takeScreenshot()" of all open windows (so the Desktop would call it on all the programs w/ open windows). VirtualBox could define its handler for "takeScreenshot()" to simulate calling this "takeScreenshot()" on all the apps it is simulating. I'm not sure if this is how it works at all, which is why I'm asking here.

Comment: Yeah, that's not how it works at all. Taking a screenshot involves opening a DC (device context) to the window in question, and reading the bits on the screen with BitBlt. Screenshots don't involve WM_PAINT or anything similar. A Win32 application will be unaware that the pixel copying process is happening. You might be able to prevent the Print Screen keystroke from doing its job, but you won't be able to detect another application simply reading bits off the screen.

Comment: @Claudiu: Actually, if you have a running (but not focused) Virtualbox window, and you press PrintScreen, nothing will be passed to the virtual computer. No Printscreen key, no message, *nothing*. Tested and verified.

Comment: @Greg: Is it possible to detect whether some application is reading bits off the screen?

Comment: This is not true.  Or at least one can detect if running inside a VM and stop working  https://superuser.com/questions/1128339/how-can-i-detect-if-im-within-a-vm-or-not

Answer (score 7):

What if I use a video camera? What if I capture the video coming between the computer and the monitor?

I'll be surprised to learn there's any practical way to do this.

Comment: still working on that bionic arm prototype which will disguise itself as a licence dongle! It'll just strangle the user if they attempt to use video cam corder or camera.

Answer (score 7):

This is never going to work. Not only that, but attempts to provide this level of security are going to inconvenience 99% of your legitimate users.

You perhaps are best to approach the problem from the angle of trying to identify unwanted uses/copies of your information and approach the people/companies using that information.

Copyright law is appropriate for this approach, but I understand that there are some intances where this approach is not available.

Answer (score 6):

You can (unreliably) do this by using [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990.aspx).

[Here is a complete VB.NET example.](http://jo0ls-dotnet-stuff.blogspot.com/2008/12/vbnet-global-keyboard-hook-to-detect.html)

However, there are many ways around this.  A hook installed after yours will "override" your hook.  Users can take pictures of their screen in many ways, as described in this thread.  I'd try to consider other options for protection than this.

Answer (score 3):

First, comments about using a virtual machine are completely pointless -- it is much easier to detect windows running under a virtualizer than to detect a screenshot being taken.

A good way to make screenshots difficult would be to rewrite your program to run in full screen mode under some ancestral dos extender.

A good way to ban 95% of users who ever attempted to take a screenshot is to display a huge flashing banner on startup ("screenshots prohibited! you be banned!"), and detect user pressing PrtScrn during the following 15 seconds.

Comment: Hah at the last paragraph =).

Comment: "much easier to detect windows running under a virtualizer" - yeah, so I'm running my legitimately licensed copy of WinXP in a VM on Linux; and your point is...?

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty hard to stop it completely... A user who is determined enough could just take a photo of the screen with a digital camera.

Answer (score 2):

Another reason why I think it will be impossible to achieve this:

A long time ago, I failed to make a screen capture of the content of Windows Media Player, because (I assumed) WMP streamed that content to the videocard right away. (Fun detail: after pasting the screen capture, the video would continue playing in MS Paint, but saving the image would eventually yield a black square). Anyway, using VNC made it very easy to get the screen capture after all.

Comment: I don't think Media Player does this to prevent screenshots--that is a side effect. Any overlay like that cannot be captured normally. However, if you turn off hardware acceleration, it won't use overlay and you can take a screen shot of it.

Comment: Indeed, I also think it is a side effect. (Though Microsoft might like to stop screen recording for DRM protected content.)

Answer (score 1):

The way I usually take screenshots (from C#) is by calling BitBlt, which is the basis of a lot of screen painting. Not sure how you'd intercept calls to it in any meaningful way, since probably every program on the system uses it at a low level.

Comment: I've seen a proof of concept code in a 1st person shooter cheat program, which froze the screenshot thread until the cheat HUD was disabled. I think it hooked BitBlt or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you really can't because one can always run your program in a window with virtual machine, then using a capture program on the outside platform, and knowing if this is happaning is mighty difficult. I suggest thinking more in ways of special rendering pace or interlacing, special contrasts, etc...

You can also run your outputs to the screen as if it was a movie, encode it with a low rate and resolution encoder, so that a still capture every 100ms will be in such a low quality that it would be worthless. (have you ever freezed a low quality movie?)

however you really should consider using other ways to protect your info.

Answer (score -1):

there is one way that i think might stop it. learn about the technology that blurs a graphical display when it is duplicated for example.

screenshot,
photographed by digital camera
screenshot from virtual os.

play with it , who knows  you might invent something that will make u millions.

Comment: "blurs a graphical display when it is duplicated" - that is sci-fi, not actual technology. The bits that become the display image are duplicated and modified a lot before they make it from the program through the OS to the hardware. The real issue here is deciphering intent, which is hard enough with humans, let alone computer instructions.