# Prevent download of .mov videos

Tags: jquery, download, mov

How do I prevent download of .mov when using JQuery Media Plugin to show .mov vidoes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. If the user can watch any video online then you're sending the video to them anyway and they are downloading it. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790190/is-it-possible-to-protect-from-downloading-a-video-from-a-site/1790206#1790206) for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You can't on the client side.  You have to stop the download on the server side.

JQuery is a JavaScript Framework. Anything the client can see in JavaScript, they can disable or change.

Answer (score 1):

Once the video is shown on the browser, the video is out of your hand.
The only way to control this is modifying the video player plugin used at client side to exchange a few handshaking messages with your web server before delivering the video. This can partially help but still doesn't resolve the issue completely.

-A