# Is there HTML embeddable audio player which prevents downloading of the audio it plays?

Tags: audio, mp3, flash

I'm looking for an audio player (like jplayer) which can be embedded in a HTML page which will allow MP3's to be played but not downloaded.

The problem: Flash players request the audio file from the server so the URL of the MP3 is present in the HTML source and can be copy/pasted in to the address bar to download the track. This will inherently be the problem with most players.

Possible solution: The player accepts some "encrypted" (non-playable) format which is then decoded inside the player. Anything like this exist?

I am not looking for solutions which sound like:

- Obfuscating the URL of the MP3
- Preventing downloading of the MP3 from third party sites (eg. forums) using .htaccess
- Embedding the mp3 inside a flash movie unless this can be automated, since mp3's are uploaded on a regular basis.
- Having a URL which only works for a certain period of time

Comment: Can't be done. Same issue was raised here: [Is it possible to protect from downloading a video from a site.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790190/is-it-possible-to-protect-from-downloading-a-video-from-a-site) - there is no difference between audio and video in this respect. You could try some sort of DRM, but even then your system can be defeated by anyone (without technical expertise, for the cost of $0.50), using this: http://www.amazon.com/3-5mm-Stereo-Male-Cable-ft/dp/B0002ZPJZO

Comment: Agreed, recording the audio output can not be prevented.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this answers your question, but... Have you tried streaming your audio files via flash? I have never heard of someone being able to download a file which was dynamicly called through actionscript... but maybe i just don't know what i am talking about...