# HTML5 : How to pass extra data to HTML5 video player

Tags: html, webkit

How to pass extra data to HTML5 video player,
like "Video name" so that play will display "Video name" some where on the screen. 
Or "Video Copy control info" so that browser will restrict the user to save file.

I could not find any attributes in VIDEO tag to specify these things.
Please help to pass some data from HTML space to browser's internal.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cant restrict video download. But can make it harder or some workaround. Check this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756837/prevent-html5-video-from-being-downloaded-right-click-saved)

Answer (score 0):

> How to pass extra data to HTML5 video player, like "Video name" so that play will display "Video name" some where on the screen.

Video elements provide no special features for that.

Create a paragraph, heading, div, or some other element. Then put a text node in it. Then add it to the DOM (e.g. immediately after the video element). Add CSS to taste.

> Or "Video Copy control info" so that browser will restrict the user to save file.

You cannot prevent users from saving files that the browser has to download in order to play.