# How to protect MP4 video online but still be playable/accessible on iPad/iPhone devices

Tags: ios, video, streaming, copy-protection

I have MP4 videos that people log in online to access. **I need the videos to be playable/accessible on an iPad/iPhone, but still have some very basic protection on them**. How can I do that?

I'm aware that putting the videos in a htaccess password-protected folder makes them inaccessible to iPad users, and even using htaccess to block hotlinking/direct-linking causes the videos to be inaccessible to an iPad user, even if the videos are in the same directory the users are currently in.

I understand that the videos can be downloaded by anyone using a Downloader plugin, and I'm not trying to have unrealistic bullet-proof security, I just don't want someone to be able to link directly to my videos saying, "Hey, you can watch those videos she's selling for free by clicking here:
ww w.mysite.com/private/video1.mp4 (that's not a real link, just an example)

I would think a lot of people have similar issues (wanting to protect online video in some way but still have them playable on an iPad/tablet/iPhone).  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: this may be of help, there's no definite way to stop someone from downloading as you already know, however you can make it harder, using html5, and if I remember right, ipads and iphone's can play html5 video.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756837/prevent-html5-video-from-being-downloaded-right-click-saved