# How to encrypt the video source while away from someone want download it?

Tags: html, video, encryption

I just want to make the video source encrypted and stay away from user want download the video. So how can i encrypt the video source?

Can we make the encrypt url of the video with **html & css**? If not, how to do it in another language?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23344117/disable-html5-video-download

Comment: I mean how to encrypt the video url in html or css. So how I can do it? Or encrypt it with other language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you "encrypt" the URL while your user's browser need the URL of the video, this means that your user's browser can "decrypt" it. So the user can also do it.

So you can't but [you can make it harder to download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756837/prevent-html5-video-from-being-downloaded-right-click-saved).

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Define the string
var href = 'https://www.bigbuckbunny.org/';

// Encode the String
var encodedString = btoa(href);
console.log('encodedString : ', encodedString);

// Decode the String
var decodedString = atob(encodedString);
console.log('decodedString : ', decodedString);
```

you can use native *base64* for decoding and encoding strings

`atob()`

`btoa()`

**Encrypt**

`btoa("https://www.bigbuckbunny.org/");`

Comment: Keep in mind that **it won't prevent the download**, just make it a little harder. *User just have to write `atob(url);` in his console.*

Comment: yes i gave the reference to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23344117/disable-html5-video-download where we have same scenario . Question Author specify 
`how to encrypt the video url in html`. so gave example for simple encrypt of string

Comment: This is NOT encryption.