# How to prevent saving files asp.net mvc 4 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, download

I 'm currently working on creating a web learning portal using ASP.NET MVC 4, where my clients requirement is that the end user should not be able to save the file. The save restriction is applicable on all video type files, images, pdf, word docs and powerpoint type files.

I understand the following exceptions and the client is good with this:

1. User can make use of print screen
2. copy-paste text

I need your guidance how best to accomplish this.

For video, I came across the following link http://www.strathweb.com/2013/01/asynchronously-streaming-video-with-asp-net-web-api/.

Thanks,
Hemant.

I came across this online tool http://www.docspal.com/ but they doesn't seems to provide any API for the developers.

Am I the only one with this requirement :(

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to stop users from copying documents from the website.

However, just to lower it down, you should be able to disable right click which may at least decrease the number of users that will try to copy your content. Do something like following in jQuery.

```
$(document).bind('contextmenu', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('Right Click is not allowed');
});
```

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756837/prevent-html5-video-from-being-downloaded-right-click-saved) for more.