# obfuscating video url / video link

Tags: php, html5-video, obfuscation, opencart2.x

Is there any way from which i can obfuscate my video url or video link ? I am embedding video in `<video>` of html 5. I have disabled right click of the page using jquery. But still user can download video thru download manager. I want to restrict it. How can i do it?

My website is in Opencart 2

Comment: In my dictionary nothing is impossible but out of two choice one has to be impossible. To download is possible but to stop someone from downloading is impossible.

Comment: Can i obfuscat the URL itself then?

Comment: If you dont want your visitors to see the videos its ok. But if users can view it then obviously the downloaders too and they can download it even if the urls are obfuscated.

Comment: ohh. Then to protect videos, i should use video hosting place like viemo ???

Comment: There are downloaders even to download videos from vimeo site. Check in google.

Answer (score 0):

If the user can view the video, you **CAN'T** restrict the download.
As a side note, any attempts to restrict user access to elements that he/she can see or interact are a waste of time, any savvy user will bypass them easily.

Comment: There is no way that i can restrict him downloading my video?

Comment: I'm afraid not. Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9756909/797495