# re-enable disabled menu "save video as" chrome ext or chrome itself "Save Video As"

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

How can I re-enable the "Save Video As" option when it is disabled on a video?

This is basically the opposite of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756837/prevent-html5-video-from-being-downloaded-right-click-saved).

Is there a global command I can send to the chrome command line which re-enables this option?

Or is there a simple extension I could use?

Comment: re-enable disabled menu “save video as” chrome ext or chrome itself “Save Video As”

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible (at least in one way)

If we are using this method to "block" the menu context of the video

```
<video oncontextmenu="return false;">
   <source src="https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/360/Big_Buck_Bunny_360_10s_2MB.mp4"/>
</video>
```

Then, all you need to do is to select video element (using `dev-tools`) and reverse the blocking command. For instance:

```
document.querySelector('body > video').oncontextmenu="return true"
```

Will re-enable the "right click menu" + allows you to download video using the "save video as..." option

As noted in accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9756909/4062197) this is a bad practice because experienced users that already familiar with `dev-tools` can by-pass this easily. If you intend to protect your videos, please consider using a cloud service that specialized in that specific task.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a definitive way, but saving the video information, deleting the  tag and creating another one in its place deletes the event that prevents the context menu.

```
function unblockVideos(){
    document.querySelectorAll('video').forEach(function(video){
        let videoHtml = video.outerHTML;

        let container = document.createElement('div');
        let newVideo = toElement(videoHtml);

        container.append(newVideo);
        newVideo.outerHTML = videoHtml;

        video.parentElement.insertBefore(newVideo, video);
        container.remove();
        video.remove();

        // to-element.js v1.0.1
        function toElement(string) {
            let wrapper = document.createElement('div');
            wrapper.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
            wrapper.firstChild.outerHTML = string.trim();
            return wrapper.firstChild;
        };
    });
};
unblockVideos();
```

However, if you only need to do this in chrome, you can cancel the event with the getEventListeners() function

```
// getEventListeners()

function unblockVideosChrome(){
    document.querySelectorAll('video').forEach(function(video){
        let events = getEventListeners(video);
        if(events.contextmenu){
            events.contextmenu.forEach(function(thisEvent){
                video.removeEventListener('contextmenu', thisEvent.listener);
            });
        };
    });
};
unblockVideosChrome();
```