# How to protect video from download like youtube

Tags: asp.net-mvc, video, youtube, video-streaming

I want the videos that I play on my site should only be streamed but should not be accessible to download like youtube.

If look for datasource of video in youtube video player find a url like 
https://www.youtube.com/4524cd9d-c4a5-4b38-92de-5fa1732e0a99

Youtube protect direct access to video url by error 404, but the same url load video in `<video>` tag in youtube video player.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBxjP.png

How can I do it like youtube with Asp.net MVC?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent HTML5 video from being downloaded (right-click saved)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756837/prevent-html5-video-from-being-downloaded-right-click-saved)

Answer (score 1):

Practically it is not possible. you may describe some copyright law in case of downloads and may use watermark and other techniques. But, Its not possible to stop one from downloading media content using browser.

Answer (score 1):

Youtube videos are downloadable (especially from the page source code, if you know the tricks...)

Anyways in your in your picture, it shows `mediasource` so they are using [**MediaSource API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource) to feed fragments of video data to the decoder (via video tag).

See if these [**research links**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?site=&source=hp&q=%22html5%22+media+source+tutorial) help you to get started.

When you understand how it works, try this tutorial : https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2011/11/Stream-video-using-the-MediaSource-API