# how can I protect my videos from download in WordPress template?

Tags: wordpress, security, video, download

I wanna upload my tutorial videos on a WordPress website. I was wondering if there is any solution to protect these videos from download. I'd rather if students can only use them online.

the videos will upload to a private host and using embedded links I'm gonna make them visible on my website. but I need them to be protected from the download.

is it possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9756909/3645650

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent HTML5 video from being downloaded (right-click saved)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756837/prevent-html5-video-from-being-downloaded-right-click-saved)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so..

The principle of the video is to send content on the computer of those who watch it, I think there will always be a way to download the video... it will be more or less difficult, but possible.