# Make a file visible at view but not downloadable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I am showing a `.stl` file at my Blade view like:

```
var stl_viewer=new StlViewer(document.getElementById("stl_cont"), {
    auto_rotate:true,
    auto_resize: true,
    cameray: 30,
    allow_drag_and_drop:true,

    models: [ {
        id:0,
        //It can be direct link or something it doesn't matter.
        filename:"{{Storage::url($file->path)}}"
    } ]
});
```

HTML Code is:

```
<div id="stl_cont"  style="min-height: 400px;"></div>
```

When user inspects the page they can find the link and they can download the file directly.

I don't want this to happen.

Comment: Since the browser has to download the File to display it that’s not possible as asked. Does this answer your question? [Prevent HTML5 video from being downloaded (right-click saved)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756837/prevent-html5-video-from-being-downloaded-right-click-saved)

Comment: I am looking for ways to hide the link from users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved my issue with  `base64_encode function`.

First, I send the URL encrypted:

```
$encrypted = base64_encode($file->path);
    return view('product', compact('product','encrypted'));
```

Then I get data into a variable on-page javascript.

```
var tboe  = '{{$encrypted}}';
```

This variable becomes global and I get the variable from separated .js file like:

```
   //example
   var file = atob(tboe);
```

I believe this makes the user reach the file hard. I can't find another way.

Comment: base64 is not an encryption. It is a different base numbering system like binary (base 2) or hexadecimal (base 16) or decimal (base 10). I don't think anyone would ever suggest that converting a number to hex is encrypting it

Comment: Since I can't find any solutions to my problem I decided to go through this way. I tried Crypt::encrypt(URL) but I can't make it encrypt at javascript.

Comment: The short story is, the browser needs to read the URL for the page to work. There is no way around it. And the browser is something the client controls

Comment: Just look at the network tab and load the page - the url of the file is plainly visible. You either don’t load the file and do (whatever) a different way, or you do load the file directly and there is no way to stop the user from accessing the file, because they already have it.

Comment: I decided to send the file to the free products.