# How does this site prevent users from downloading videos?

Tags: laravel, download, http-live-streaming, m3u8, hls.js

I am writing an online training program and I want the videos **not to be downloaded** by the **user**! That's why I need a player to prevent this.

I want to like this site
execute it On this site, the video is played as hls, but when I click on the URLs that receive m3u8 or ts files from the server. The error gives no access! So the user cannot request the video from the server through the URL being played.

In addition, the signature in the URL changes every time the page is refreshed!

https://roocket.ir/series/learn-laravel/episode/1

[image]

Comment: FYI I can still record my screen :D, hope this [helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756837/prevent-html5-video-from-being-downloaded-right-click-saved)

Comment: there is no way to 100% prevent that, at best you make it difficult enough so that 99% of people will not bother.

Answer (score 1):

> I am writing an online training program and I want the videos not to be downloaded by the user!

Impossible.

> That's why I need a player to prevent this.

The player has little to do with protecting your content.  At best, you can use DRM to encrypt your content which will make it much more of a hassle to rip, but won't totally stop it.

> I want to like this site execute it On this site, the video is played as hls, but when I click on the URLs that receive m3u8 or ts files from the server. The error gives no access! So the user cannot request the video from the server through the URL being played.

I assure you without a doubt that the files can be accessed, and that this scheme offers little-to-no protection of the content.  Signed URLs like these are meant to protect from hotlinking, embedding, and unauthorized users.  Once a user has an account though, they can of course rip the video.

If the user can see it/hear it, they can capture it.  It is impossible to get around this.  At best, you can DRM and watermark your content so that it's harder to decrypt, and identifiable if that content is eventually stolen.