# Is there a way to prevent detection by the website when a screenshot is taken using a Mac Os X Safari browser?

Tags: python, safari, screenshot, virtual-machine, browser-detection

There is a thread discussing Darwin notifications being sent after a screenshot is taken. Does this apply to websites viewed via Safari? Do the same restrictions apply to PC sytems? Would taking the picture via a Python script in Linux or running Safari in a VM circumvent detection?

Answer (score 2):

if you are talking about [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121970/notification-of-or-detecting-screenshot-being-taken), please note that it seems to apply only to the iPhone. there is nothing similar in any decent web browser on any desktop platform (plus, anybody can put a proxy to filter this kind of notification, or create its own browser out of off-the-shelf components).

note that rendering a webpage in a browser is the same as taking a screenshot: the browser needs to know what to render on the screen and how to draw it. this is the purpose of HTML and CSS, to describe what and how to render a page, so the simple fact of downloading the content of a webpage gives enough informations for rendering into whatever you want, be it a screen, a picture saved or a file on disk.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying. There was an additional thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774925/detect-when-users-take-screenshots-of-my-program) that discussed the same concept with regards to PC systems. It is my understanding that when you grab the image (ie. shift-command-4) a signal is sent indicating that you are taking an image (analogous to WM_HOTKEY). Am I correct in assuming this?

Thanks for your response by the way.

Comment: there is indeed the possibility that the OS sends a signal to the application (the browser in this case) that the user takes a screenshot. but this signal has to be caught by the browser and made available to the webpage (through JavaScript or such) in order to signal the server of this user action. i am pretty sure that most browsers on a PC are NOT doing so.