# Detect source of remote desktop connection

Tags: c#, windows, delphi, remote-desktop, terminal-services

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159910/determine-if-a-program-is-running-on-a-remote-desktop) tells me how to detect a remote desktop session.

Do anybody know if it's possible to find out from where the remote connection was initialized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it's in windows use netstat to check which machines you are connected to and on which ports and just parse out the address for the one that uses the port that remote desktop uses.

Comment: And since remote desktop always uses port 3389, this will work. Thanks!

Comment: This would only work if you have a single remote connection else you cannot see which sessions connects to which remote machine.

Comment: Is the output of `netstat` affected by the current locale? That can make string parsing *much* more complicated. Prefer an API solution over one that relies on external programs and variable output formats.

Comment: yea, I agree it's a nasty a solution, but it's a fast one.

Comment: remote desktop doesn't always use port 3389, this can be user defined, and often is for security if a vpn isn't being used

Answer (score 10):

@Vegar, you can use the  [WTSEnumerateSessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsenumeratesessionsa)  and [WTSQuerySessionInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsquerysessioninformationa)  functions to retrieve this info.

check  this [link](http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2007/10/31/how-to-get-client-ip-address/) for an example using the [Jedi Api Headers](http://blog.delphi-jedi.net/jedi-api-headers/).

check this code.

```
program ProjectTsInfo;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

Uses
  Windows,
  JwaWinType,
  JwaWtsApi32,
  JwaWinsock2,
  SysUtils,
  TypInfo;


type
  PWtsSessionInfoAArray = ^TWtsSessionInfoAArray;
  TWtsSessionInfoAArray = array[0..ANYSIZE_ARRAY-1] of WTS_SESSION_INFOA;

//Get the info for all clients connected
procedure GetAll_TSClientsInfo;
var
  SessionInfoAArray: PWtsSessionInfoAArray;
  ClientAddr       : PWtsClientAddress;
  ClientName       : PAnsiChar;
  //ClientInfo       : PWTSCLIENT;
  RetBytes         : Cardinal;
  IPAddr           : String;
  i                : integer;
  pCount           : Cardinal;
  SessionId        : Cardinal;
begin

  if WtsEnumerateSessions(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER, 0, 1, PWTS_SESSION_INFO(SessionInfoAArray),  pCount) then
  begin

    for i := 0 to pCount - 1 do
    begin
      SessionId:=SessionInfoAArray^[i].SessionId;
      WTSQuerySessionInformation(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER, SessionId, WTSClientAddress, Pointer(ClientAddr), RetBytes);
      WTSQuerySessionInformation(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER, SessionId, WTSClientName, Pointer(ClientName), RetBytes);
      //WTSQuerySessionInformation(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER, SessionId, WTSClientInfo, Pointer(ClientInfo), RetBytes);  //This value is supported for Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista with SP1.

     try
      case ClientAddr^.AddressFamily of
        AF_INET:
          IPAddr:= Format('%d.%d.%d.%d', [
            ClientAddr^.Address[2],
            ClientAddr^.Address[3],
            ClientAddr^.Address[4],
            ClientAddr^.Address[5]
            ]);
        else
        IPAddr:= '<unknow>';
      end;

      WriteLn(Format('Session Id  : %d ', [SessionId]));
      WriteLn(Format('Client Name : %s ', [ClientName]));
      WriteLn(Format('Station Name: %s ', [SessionInfoAArray^[i].pWinStationName]));
      WriteLn(Format('State       : %s ', [GetEnumName(TypeInfo(WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS),integer(SessionInfoAArray^[i].State))]));
      WriteLn(Format('IP          : %s ', [IPAddr]));

      //supported for Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista with SP1.
      {
      WriteLn(Format('ClientName      : %s ', [ClientInfo^.ClientName]));
      WriteLn(Format('Domain          : %s ', [ClientInfo^.Domain]));
      WriteLn(Format('UserName        : %s ', [ClientInfo^.UserName]));
      WriteLn(Format('WorkDirectory   : %s ', [ClientInfo^.WorkDirectory]));
      WriteLn(Format('InitialProgram  : %s ', [ClientInfo^.InitialProgram]));
      WriteLn(Format('EncryptionLevel : %d ', [ClientInfo^.EncryptionLevel]));
      WriteLn(Format('HRes            : %d ', [ClientInfo^.HRes]));
      WriteLn(Format('VRes            : %d ', [ClientInfo^.VRes]));
      WriteLn(Format('ColorDepth      : %d ', [ClientInfo^.ColorDepth]));
      WriteLn(Format('ClientDirectory : %s ', [ClientInfo^.ClientDirectory]));
      }
      Writeln('');

   finally
      WTSFreeMemory(ClientAddr);
      WTSFreeMemory(ClientName);
   end;
    end;
  end;

  WtsFreeMemory(SessionInfoAArray);
end;

//Get the ip address of the actual connected client
function GetIpActualClient : string;
var
  ClientAddr       : PWtsClientAddress;
  RetBytes         : Cardinal;
  IPAddr           : String;
  SessionId        : Cardinal;
begin
      SessionId:=WTS_CURRENT_SESSION;
      WTSQuerySessionInformation(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER, SessionId, WTSClientAddress, Pointer(ClientAddr), RetBytes);
      try
        case ClientAddr^.AddressFamily of
          AF_INET:
            IPAddr:= Format('%d.%d.%d.%d', [
              ClientAddr^.Address[2],
              ClientAddr^.Address[3],
              ClientAddr^.Address[4],
              ClientAddr^.Address[5]
              ]);
          else
          IPAddr:= '<unknow>';
        end;
      Result:=IPAddr;
      finally
       WTSFreeMemory(ClientAddr);
      end;
end;

begin
  Writeln('IP Actual client '+GetIpActualClient);
  Writeln('-----------------------------------');

  GetAll_TSClientsInfo;
  Readln;
end.
```

**UPDATE**

As @Remko says, the **WTSQuerySessionInformation** function with the  **WTSClientAddress** type, can return the local IP of the client. if you wanna get the real ip you can use the WinStationGetRemoteIPAddress helper function located in the JwaWinSta unit.

```
Var
Port    : Word;
IpAddr  : WideString;
Begin
WinStationGetRemoteIPAddress(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER,WTS_CURRENT_SESSION,IpAddr,Port);
End;
```

Comment: Is it even necessary to use `WTSEnumerateSessions`? I think using `wts_Current_Session` for the session ID would be sufficient.

Comment: To get you own session, use ProcessIdToSessionId

Comment: @Rob you are right the WTSEnumerateSessions function is to get the info for all sessions, i posted an example using wts_Current_Session and WTSEnumerateSessions.  ;)

Comment: I'm trying the WinStationGetRemoteIPaddress( ) now. I'm at home with a RDC to my office computer. When I call this method, it returns the ip address of my router, not my local machine.
Btw, netstat returns WORKGROUP in this case. Not too useful...

Comment: @Vegar: yes of course it does, you make the connection with your *external* ip which in most cases is the ip that your router or modem has. WinStationGetRemoteIPAddress returns the IP address as reported by Terminal Server and it will match output of netstat on the server.

Answer (score 7):

For me, this worked, it gets the name of the machine connected.

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CLIENTNAME")
```

Answer (score 4):

WTSQuerySessionInformation returns the client IP as the client reports it, this will probably be (one) of it's local IP Address. If you want to know the REAL ip address and port that is connected you can use WinStationQueryInformationW with information class WinStationRemoteAddress.
You will need my unit JwaWinsta from the Jedi Apilib.

I have provided a simple wrapper in the same unit as well:

```
function WinStationGetRemoteIPAddress(hServer: HANDLE; SessionId: DWORD;
  var RemoteIPAddress: WideString; var Port: WORD): Boolean;
```

Comment: +1 @Remko you are right the WTSClientAddress can report the local ip instead of the real ip. i update my answer. p.s : thanks very much for you great work  in the Jedi Api Headers. ;)

Answer (score 1):

try running [qwinsta](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731503%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the remote session ID and get the IP address that connected via Citrix you can use the below.  This was designed to run when a user connects to a server via a citrix session and display/create a string for the IP address it is connecting from.

```
// Prints out ICA or RDP session ID of current user & gets ICA session clientAddress variable

using System;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace ViaRegedit
{
    class Program03
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Obtain an instance of RegistryKey for the CurrentUser registry 
            RegistryKey rkCurrentUser = Registry.CurrentUser;
            // Obtain the test key (read-only) and display it.
            RegistryKey rkTest = rkCurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Remote");

            foreach (string valueName in rkTest.GetSubKeyNames())
            {
                //Getting path to RDP/Citrix session ID
                string RDPICApath = "";
                if (rkTest.OpenSubKey(valueName) != null && rkTest.OpenSubKey(valueName) != null) { RDPICApath = rkTest.OpenSubKey(valueName).ToString(); }
                Console.WriteLine("Getting CurrentUser ICA-RDP path from string = " + RDPICApath);

                //Split RDPICApath to get session number
                string RDPICAnumber = RDPICApath.Substring(RDPICApath.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
                Console.WriteLine("Current User RDPICAnumber = " + RDPICAnumber);

                //Getting reg local machine info for Citrix based on RDP/Citrix session ID "RDPICAnumber"
                string regLocal = @"SOFTWARE\Citrix\Ica\Session\" + RDPICAnumber + @"\Connection";
                RegistryKey localKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
                RegistryKey citrixKey = localKey.OpenSubKey(regLocal);
                Console.WriteLine("Registry " + citrixKey + " Does Exist - going to get ClientAddress");
                //getting clietAddress var from citrixKey 
                string clientAddress = "";
                if (citrixKey != null && citrixKey.GetValue("clientAddress") != null)
                    {clientAddress = citrixKey.GetValue("clientAddress").ToString();}
                    Console.WriteLine("Getting current user clientAddress from string = " + clientAddress); 
            }
            rkTest.Close();
            rkCurrentUser.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

}
```