# c# getting ip address of user who remotely connect to machine

Tags: c#, windows-services, ip-address, remote-connection

I am using following piece of c# code in windows service to capture Remote connect and disconnect events.

How I can get the IPaddress of end user who remotely connect to that machine.

```
protected override void OnSessionChange(SessionChangeDescription changeDescription)
 {
        switch (changeDescription.Reason)
        {
            case SessionChangeReason.RemoteConnect:
                //Remote Connect
                break;
            case SessionChangeReason.RemoteDisconnect:
                //Remote Disconnect
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found related solution in c#, it's using PInvoke `WTSQuerySessionInformation` with `WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSClientAddress`

For more details you can go here:
[Grabbing Information of a Terminal Services Session Programmatically](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/111430/Grabbing-Information-of-a-Terminal-Services-Sessio)

Note from Selvin: solution doesn't free returned buffer ... you sould call `WTSFreeMemory(pAddress)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to your question;

[Detect source of remote desktop connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461325/detect-source-of-remote-desktop-connection)

It simply indicates that you can query the connections and parse them.