# Getting Operating System using c#

Tags: c#

I've been conducting *research* on a way of getting the current system operating system using `C#`.

It seems there isn't one single answer, as in many cases, but they all seem to be a few years old. Some which I attempted to use and base my code around, **didn't work**.

References: [1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5956c04f-072a-406c-ae6a-cc8b3a207936/systemenvironmentosversionversionmajor?forum=csharpgeneral), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819934/detect-windows-7-in-net/2819962), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15511021/how-to-programmatically-tell-the-difference-between-xp-64-bit-and-server-2003-64/15511176), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138294/determining-if-the-program-is-running-on-windows-server/3138781), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860459/determine-os-using-environment-osversion), *etc*

So I came up with my own code:

```
var os = System.Environment.OSVersion;
string currentOS = null;

switch(os.Platform)
{
    case PlatformID.Win32S:
        currentOS = "Windows 3.1";
        break;
    case PlatformID.Win32Windows:
        switch(os.Version.Minor)
        {
            case 0:
                currentOS = "Windows 95";
                break;
            case 10:
                currentOS = "Windows 98";
                break;
            default:
                currentOS = "Unknown";
                break;
        }
        break;
    case PlatformID.Win32NT:
        switch(os.Version.Major)
        {
            case 3:
                currentOS = "Windows NT 3.51";
                break;
            case 4:
                currentOS = "Windows NT 4.0";
                break;
            case 5:
                switch(os.Version.Minor)
                {
                    case 0:
                        currentOS = "Windows 2000";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        currentOS = "Windows XP";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        currentOS = "Windows 2003";
                        break;
                    default:
                        currentOS = "Unknown";
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 6:
                switch(os.Version.Minor)
                {
                    case 0:
                        currentOS = "Windows Vista";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        currentOS = "Windows 2008";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        currentOS = "Windows 7";
                        break;
                    default:
                        currentOS = "Unknown";
                        break;
                }
                break;
            default:
                currentOS = "Unknown";
                break;
        }
        break;
    case PlatformID.WinCE:
        currentOS = "Windows CE";
        break;
    case PlatformID.Unix:
        currentOS = "Unix";
        break;
    default:
        currentOS = "Unknown";
        break;
}
```

I have tested this code on my laptop, running windows 7, it returns `windows 2008`. What could be the cause of this, is there anything I should change?

Comment: The code is simply wrong, it's saying that version 6.1 is `Windows 2008` instead of `Windows 7`. It also doesn't cope with `Windows 8` in any way.#

Comment: Well *Windows 7* is **NT 6.1** as well as *Windows Server 2008 R2* is. Check out this list for further information: [List of Microsoft Windows versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Windows_versions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because 6.1 is for Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008, 6.2 is Windows 8.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

According to Microsoft 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832(v=vs.85).aspx

In your situation, 6.1 is refer to `Window 7/Windows Server 2008 R2`

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832(v=vs.85).aspx), Windows 7 is actually 6.1, so I guess your case statement is not valid. There's no way, using the version, to differenciate Windows 7 from windows 2008 server

Answer (score 1):

From the [official list of Windows versions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms724832(v=vs.85).aspx), version 6.1 is `Windows 7` but your code says it is `Windows 2008` (which by the way isn't a thing.)