# Check whether application is running under Terminal Services as opposed to Remote Desktop

Tags: c#, .net, terminal-services

I have a .NET application where I need to be able to disallow running it on a Terminal Services server for licensing reasons. I am aware of the `SystemInformation` API to determine if a program is running under a remote session (as detailed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159910/determine-if-a-program-is-running-on-a-remote-desktop) for example). However, that API does not distinguish between an application running on a normal server which has the 2 allowed remote desktop sessions and a full-blown terminal server which might have 500 sessions running on it.

Is there a simple programmatic way that I can determine whether the application is running on a full-on terminal server?

I am fine with the assumption that more than 2 allowed sessions means a full-on terminal server, and I am also fine with P/Invoke if that's what's required.

Comment: I'm curious as to how this information would be helpful. I don't know of anything in the RDS API that exposes this. You could potentially check whether the server has RD licensing servers configured.

Comment: @DanPorts - The information would be helpful because it's a business requirement that the software is not able to be used on a Terminal Services environment.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the below code:

```
    string s = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SessionName");
```

If the value of s is "Console", it could be running in terminal services. On the other hand, if the value is something like "RDP-Tcp#01", it is running under Remote Desktop.