# How to know if my application is controlled using Remote Desktop?

Tags: c#, remote-desktop

Description of event [SystemmEvents.SessionSwitch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionswitch?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)

> Occurs when the currently logged-in user has changed.

The [SessionSwitchEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.sessionswitcheventargs?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) have a property [Reason](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.sessionswitcheventargs.reason?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Win32_SessionSwitchEventArgs_Reason) which tells you the reason of the event.

If remote desktop connects or disconnects, this event is raised.

- When starting remote desktop: Reason == SessionSwitchReason.RemoteConnect
- When remote desktop is closed: Reason == SessionSwitchReason.RemoteDisconnect

.

```
class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += SessionSwitched;
        IsRemoteSession = SystemParameters.IsRemoteSession;

        Logger.LogTrace("ViewModel constructed. Remote Session {0}", this.IsRemoteSession);
    }

    public bool IsRemoteSession {get; set;}

    private void SessionSwitched(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
    {
        this.IsRemoteSession = SystemParameters.IsRemoteSession;
        Logger.LogTrace("Session Switch. Reason: {0}; Remote Session {1}"
                         e.Reason, this.IsRemoteSession);
}
```

If I start the program without remote desktop, property IsRemoteSession is false. If I start remote desktop, the event is raised, but the property remains false.

However, if I start the program with remote descktop, IsRemoteSession is true. If I close remote desktop the event is raised, but the property remains true.

I also tried GetSystemMetrics, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159910/determine-if-a-program-is-running-on-a-remote-desktop), but that didn't give the correct value either, which could be expected, because SystemParameters uses GetSystemMetrics to get the values.